# Dataframe from SQL using dbplyr causes error. Writing the dataframe to csv and reading does not cause error

Tags: r, dplyr, odbc

I'm using dplyr to pull a dataframe from SQL using as.data.frame. When I pass this data into a function it runs forever. However, if I export the dataframe to csv and read it back into R, then it runs fine. I've checked that all of the datatypes are the same, i.e. str(dat1) and str(dat2) shows that all integers are integers in both cases, all factors remain factors, etc. I'm not sure where to look next as the two datasets seem identical as far as I can tell.

I've tried running the same sequence with a different SQL database. The same sequence occurs.

Here is how I import the data from SQL.

```
SQL_dat <- SQL_tbl %>%
  filter(Year == "201718") %>% 
  filter(VERSION == "G") %>%
  select(FORENAME, SURNAME, DOB, GENDER) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

I check that the SQL data and the data read from csv using:

```
str(SQL_dat)
str(CSV_dat)
```

Both show the same thing

Can anyone suggest a next step to identify where the difference may lie?